# Release of iOS 6.1 app with Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, xcode5

I'm having trouble release an iOS 6.1 app with Xcode 5. During the development we worked on Xcode 4 and then switched to Xcode 5. The application is very large and is not optimized for iOS 7. So I used iOS 6.1 SDK to compile for both iOS 6.1. Application was tested with TestFlight and it worked flawlessly on both iOS 7 and iOS 6 devices. On both devices it had same iOS6 looks, which was satisfying.

The application base SDK is set to iOS 6.1 SDK and iOS deployment target is set to same 6.1 SDK.

We sent the application in the review and it was approved. **When we released the application, we realized that it is run with iOS 7 looks on iOS 7 devices.** This currently breaks our layout.

*Is there any way to fix this and let application be released in iOS6 mode for now?*

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can do that. You have to fix every Xib for both iOS 6.1 and iOS 7 so that user can get the UX standard in whichever version of iOS they use. You have to take care of several things. Like

1. Fix status bar overlapping issue , there are lots of disscussions in stackoverflow about it.
2. Use appropriate images that matches UX standard of corresponding version.
3. You have add new launch images/ icons for iOS 7.

etc in short.

Comment: We do not want to do that. We want to keep iOS 6 default looks, even on iOS 7 devices.

Comment: I think you can't do it with Xocde 5 , if you want to keep same UI for iOS 7 then you have to design every Xib with custom images that were used in iOS 6.1. But as they have been designed with iOS 6 UX , so Apple may reject the app as it will not follow iOS UX guidelines.